# why doesn't time passes the thread in python

Tags: python-3.x

I've created a code so at a certian time it has to display a message. I tried it with a counter and it worked, but when using "strftime" it doesn't work. Can any one explain what I did wrong.

Below you'll fine the code I used.

```
import datetime, threading, time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

def foo():
    counter = 0
    next_call = time.time()
    while True:
        #counter +=1
        if(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")>=("22:00:00")):
            print("go to sleep")
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            print (datetime.datetime.now())
            next_call = next_call+1;
            time.sleep(next_call - time.time())

timerThread = threading.Thread(target=foo)
timerThread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never change the value of 'now'.  Conseqeuently it is the fixed time at which you start running this program.

You need to update it inside the loop.